# which comes first painting walls or stippling the ceiling

Tags: paint

Hope that someone can help me. I am scrapping the popcorn off my ceiling. I will be doing a knockdown. Should I paint the walls before the stippling?

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind popcorn is often there *for a reason*. Style isn't the reason, It's to conceal flaws in the ceiling. The ceiling panels are uneven because of joist issues, or, the builder specced it to allow less precise placement of joists.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would do the final coat on the ceiling and then the final coat on the walls - “cutting in” has to be done either way.

Comment: I agree always do the high work first you don’t want to have to wash down those fresh painted walls , remember to use PPE as most of the popcorn ceiling texture contains asbestos, I find getting it wet with a back pack sprayer and water makes it real easy with a nice wide tape knife, cheap plastic on the floor , when done roll it up bag then double bag and in the trash is legal in my area.

Comment: Great call, Ed.  I've done this a few times and I've found it's important to get it very wet. Not using just a little spray bottle. I've used a back pack sprayer and even a garden hose with a nozzle set to a fine mist or fine spray. Keep it good and wet. Little danger from asbestos that way.  IMHO: You won't have issues if exposed to very small amounts of asbestos.  The ppl who really suffered from asbestos where ship workers, pipe fitters who worked around and installed this stuff day after day. Industrial exposure.